# NetLogo: Assign Turtles Randomly but Equally to Different Groups

Tags: random, netlogo

I used the code below to create 50 turtles and randomly assign them to one of four different strategies (i.e. a, b, c and d):

The problem is that when I decrease the number of created turtles or when I increase the number of strategies, I face a situation where at least one of the strategies is not taken by any turtle.

```
turtles-own [ my_strategy ]

to setup
  ;; create 50 turtles and assign them randomly
  ;; to one of four different strategies
  create-turtles 50 [
    set my_strategy one-of [ "a" "b" "c" "d" ]
  ]
end
```

I need your help here to:
1.  Make sure that I do not face a situation where one or more strategies are not taken by any turtle.
2.  Make sure that the number of turtles assigned to each strategy is roughly equal.

I tried to solve the problem by using the code below, but it did not work:

```
turtles-own [ my_strategy ]

to setup
  let strategies [ "a" "b" "c" "d" ]
  let turtles-num 51
  let i 0

  create-turtles turtles-num 

  while [ not any? turtles with [  my_strategy = 0 ] ] [
    ifelse i < length strategies - 1 [ set i i + 1 ] [ set i 0 ]
    ask n-of ceiling  ( turtles-num / length strategies ) turtles with [ my_strategy = 0 ] [
      set my_strategy item i strategies
    ]
  ]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is always a risk when you use randomly-generated numbers. I don't know netlogo, but perhaps you should consider changing to a round-robin approach for allocating strategies?

Comment: how random do you want the group sizes? You can use `ask n-of` to create an exact number for a strategy and perhaps give a range for `n`. Alternatively, do the `one-of` approach (which is fully random) and then do a check after with `not any?` and simply change the strategy for a random turtle.

Comment: Thank you  Robin for your suggest. I am not from a computer science background and this is the first time I heard about the round-robin approach. I shall study it and use it in my future work.

Comment: Thank you JenB for your reply. Please see the second code above in which I tried to use `n-of` and `not any?`. However, the code did not work properly, and I do not know why. do you have any suggestion about how to fix that code? I guess the code does not work in a situation when the outcome of the division `number of turtles/number of strategies` is not an integer, which means that not all the strategies are going to be equal…

Comment: For example, `51 turtles/ 4 strategies = 12.75` which means that two strategies should have 12 turtles while the other two strategies should have 13 turtles. How can I amend the code above to cover this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should never use `who` numbers for anything in NetLogo. However, this is one of the very few occasions where it's appropriate.

From comments, you actually want equal (or as close to equal as possible) numbers in each group so you don't need to calculate the number in each group. When `turtles` are created, they are created with sequential `who` numbers. So you can use the `mod` operator to assign them to each strategy in turn.

```
turtles-own [ my_strategy ]

to setup
  ;; create 50 turtles and assign them equally
  ;; to one of four different strategies
  create-turtles 50 [
    set my_strategy item (who mod 4) [ "a" "b" "c" "d" ]
  ]
end
```